# How can I reach children below 13 years old?

Tags: children

I want to build a scooter community in the context of my city and communicate easily about events I'm planning.

Most of people who ride stunt scooters are children under 13 years old. Since it's forbidden for them to use FB I can't promote my FB page and group  to them. So how can I reach them?

This looks like a need for some old-school off-line solution.

Comment: 1 comment regarding your FB page, you may not be able to reach the children, but you can reach the parents. Try to cater to what an adult may be looking for when they try to find something for their children. But at the same time the page ought to attract children, because the parent may show it to them.

Answer (score 7):

- Reach out to schools in your area, and advertise your events through the schools.  Perhaps you can visit some schools.
- Target the parents, which you can do either through social media or by hanging leaflets at supermarkets, libraries, community centres, etc.

Social media may simply not be the right medium to reach out to small children directly.

Comment: yup, in front of my local primary school at the beginning of semester there is a bunch of leaflet-people advertising for similar actions (robotics workshops and things like that)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you visit stunt riding events, have a banner created *Join the CITY stunt scooter group*, and display it at these events.
These things are cheap nowadays.